# d3.js not scaling properly, there is a limit to what shows up on my axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I am trying to create a slider which reveals data as you slide the bar across from left to right. When I slide from right to left, my data does not show up. And secondly, the highest number the x-axis scales to is 9. I have played around with my data, if I put 8 as the highest value for the x-axis, 8 will be the highest value. But I cannot go beyond 9 for some reason. And not all my data displays even if I have all the numbers under 9.

In my data, I have two columns. One called "ep" (this is for the x-axis), and the other called "char" (this is for the y-axis).

Any ideas on how I can get the x-axis to scale properly and have my data show up?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LD V6</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family:"avenir next", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #696969;
    }

    .ticks {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .track,
    .track-inset,
    .track-overlay {
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    .track {
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: 0.3;
      stroke-width: 10px;
    }

    .track-inset {
      stroke: #dcdcdc;
      stroke-width: 8px;
    }

    .track-overlay {
      pointer-events: stroke;
      stroke-width: 50px;
      stroke: transparent;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }

    .handle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: 0.5;
      stroke-width: 1.25px;
    }



  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="vis">

</div>
<script>




var margin = {top:50, right:30, bottom:30, left:30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#vis")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);  

////////// slider //////////

var moving = false;
var currentValue = 0;
var targetValue = 200;

var playButton = d3.select("#play-button");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width])
    .clamp(true);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var slider = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slider")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + (height) + ")");

slider.append("line")
    .attr("class", "track")
    .attr("x1", x.range()[0])
    .attr("x2", x.range()[1])
  .select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
    .attr("class", "track-inset")
  .select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
    .attr("class", "track-overlay")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start.interrupt", function() { slider.interrupt(); })
        .on("start drag", function() {
          currentValue = d3.event.x;
          update(x.invert(currentValue)); 
        })
    );

//Attributes of the slider
slider.insert("g", ".track-overlay")
    .attr("class", "ticks")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 18 + ")")
 /* .selectAll("text")
    .data(x.ticks(8))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.ep); }); */

//Attributes of the slider handle   
var handle = slider.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("r", 8);

    /*
var label = slider.append("text")  
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(formatDate(startDate))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (-25) + ")")
    */

////////// plot //////////

var dataset;

var plot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "plot")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("trial_v3.csv", prepare, function(data) {
  dataset = data;
  drawPlot(dataset);

  // scale the range of the data
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.char; })]);
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ep; })]);

  // add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + ",0)");

  // add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 +"," + height + ")")

})


function prepare(d) {
  d.ep = d.ep;
  d.char = d.char;

  return d;

}



function drawPlot(data) {
  var locations = plot.selectAll(".location")
    .data(data);

  // if filtered dataset has more circles than already existing, transition new ones in
  locations.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "location")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.ep); })
    .attr("cy", function(d){  return y(d.char)}) 
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("r", 5)
      .transition()
      .duration(1200)
      .attr("r", 11
            );


  // if filtered dataset has less circles than already existing, remove excess
  locations.exit()
    .remove();

    }

function update(h) {
  // update position and text of label according to slider scale circle
  handle.attr("cx", x(h));
  /*label
    .attr("x", x(h))
    .text(formatDate(h)); */

  // filter data set and redraw plot
  var newData = dataset.filter(function(d) {
    return d.ep < h;
  })
  drawPlot(newData); 
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////// SVG 2 /////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
var svg2 = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom); 

    svg2.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height",50)

*/  

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You haven't given enough code to easily recreate your problem, so it's difficult to know what the problem is. One thing I notice looking at your code though is that you are drawing the plot before you are assigning the domain to the scale.  This means that when you use the scale with `x(d.ep)` you are using with with an improper domain. Maybe this is part of the problem. If you can post enough code to recreate the problem it will help people  give better answers.

Comment: My be this will help you. https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/ac350e2ba0f486384483f456d20797a4

Comment: @Mark_M Thank you for your comment. Please see the full code above. I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur Thanks for this reference! I will look into this.